# Fog node registration using userid password biometric data

Tags: python

shows the psecode for user registration request using the EthAdr,

Usermail, Username, password, and Bdata of a new User. The User data are hashed and stored

on the blockchain, and a new User is registered successfully. Figure 4 highlights the struct

of the smart contract, the struct contains and defines custom data types in the User detail

(UserDetail), these data types include the EthAdr, Usermail, Username, password, and Bdata

of User. Boolean data are also used to represent scenario “isUserLoggedIn” and “true or

false” binary results. The data a user must provide are included in the struct. During the

registration phase, the User registration function is initiated to register a new User with data

and parameters initialised by the SmContract; the new User is required to provide Usermail,

UserEthAdr, password and Bdata to be registered

It will be in python coding language and here blockchain smart contract will be implemented and the data should be stored in blockchain ledger

Comment: You may want to read [ask]